# How to change php binary location in OSX command line

Tags: php, mac-osx, command-line-interface

I'm trying to update where the command line gets the location of the php binary:

webserver:
/usr/bin

cli:
/opt/local/bin/php

Where can I edit so when I do 'which php' it shows me /usr/bin/php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .bashrc

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Didn't change.  I logged in as my normal user and was at the home directory, did nano .bashrc and added the above line (file was empty)

I also checked .bash_profile and it had export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:(other paths here)

Comment: Remove the .bashrc change, and edit your .bash_profile instead so that /usr/bin is first.

Answer (score 0):

It won't change the actual location, but you can make a symbolic link (shortcut) using the `ln` program.

`sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php`

That makes a shortcut from `/opt/local/bin/php` to `/usr/bin/php`. It's cleaner and more straightforward than having duplicate files or adding a directory to your `PATH`, in my opinion.